# How to remove excess syntax from email Python?

Tags: python, gmail

I am writing a script that sends new Usernames and Passwords to people using gmail in Python. The problem is that excess syntax appears in the message, which is not what I want.

```
#Sending Email containing new Username and Password
            Sub=("Password Change Request")
            Msg=("Hello, you have requested a Username and Password change."
                 "Your new credentials are Username: ",Username,"Password: ",Password,"")
            REmail=EmailF.get()
            try:
                server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
                server.ehlo()
                server.starttls()
                server.login(config.EMAIL_ADDRESS, config.PASSWORD)
                message = "Subject: {} \n\n {}".format(Sub, Msg)
                server.sendmail(config.EMAIL_ADDRESS, REmail, message)
                server.quit()
                print("Success!")
```

The variables Username and Password are random strings of characters. An example of the email produced can be seen below:

```
('Hello, you have requested a Username and Password change.Your new credentials are Username: ',
 'foo', 'Password: ', 'bar', '')
```

It should read: Hello, you have requested a Username and Password change.
                     Your new credentials are Username: Username Password: Password

Comment: can you paste the result as text also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when doing

```
message = "Subject: {} \n\n {}".format(Sub, Msg)
```

you're passing `Msg` to `str.format`. `Msg` is a `tuple`, so `str.format` tries to convert it to a representable/printable form for debug purposes. Yes, you don't want to send a mail with that.

Instead, create `Msg` as a *string*, also using `str.format`:

```
Msg="Hello, you have requested a Username and Password change.\nYour new credentials are Username: {}, Password: {}".format(Username,Password)
```

If the string is too long as is you can cut it and add parentheses, but don't put any commas (as the `tuple` will return to bite you)

```
Msg=("Hello, you have requested a Username and Password change.\n"
 "Your new credentials are Username: {}, Password: {}").format(Username,Password)
```